# MVC : Pass values from textbox to controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC.Basically I need to pass values entered in the textbox from my view to controller action method. As I enter the values in the text box and click the enter button I need to display the value on the screen. I am currently unable to do so. Please find my code below
The model class

```
 public class ProteinTrackingService
    {
        public int? Total { get; set; }
        public int Goal { get; set; }

        public void AddProtein(int? amount)
        {
            Total += amount;
        }

    }
```

The controller class

```
 public class ProteinTrackerController : Controller
    {

        ProteinTrackingService proteinTrackingService = new ProteinTrackingService();
        // GET: ProteinTracker
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Total = proteinTrackingService.Total;
            ViewBag.Goal = proteinTrackingService.Goal;
            return View();
        }

        // GET: ProteinTracker/Details/5

        public ActionResult AddProtein(ProteinTrackingService model)
        {
            proteinTrackingService.AddProtein(model.Total);
            ViewBag.Total = proteinTrackingService.Total;
            ViewBag.Goal = proteinTrackingService.Goal;

            return View("Index");
        }


    }
```

The view

```
using (Html.BeginForm("ProteinTracker", "AddProtein",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()



        <form>
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <h4>Protein Tracker</h4>
                <hr />

                Total : @ViewBag.Total
                Goal  : @ViewBag.Goal

                <input id="Text1" type="text" value="TextInput" />  <input type="Submit" value="Add"  />



            </div>
        </form>

}
```

I am modifying the code above based on your suggestions. I basically need to display the following in the view

Total : value
Goal : value

Textbox control (To enter the total) Button (pass the total to contoller) Please note that when the user clicks the Add button the total should show in above field Total : value.

New View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm( "AddProtein","ProteinTracker", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <h4>Protein Tracker</h4>
                <hr />

                 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Total, "Total" )  <hr />
                 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Goal, "Goal")   <hr />
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Total)   <hr />

                 <input type="Submit" value="Add"  />
            </div>

}
```

New Controller

public class ProteinTrackerController : Controller
{

```
ProteinTrackingService proteinTrackingService = new ProteinTrackingService();
// GET: ProteinTracker
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new ProteinTrackingService()
    { Total = proteinTrackingService.Total, Goal = proteinTrackingService.Goal };
    return View(model);

}

// GET: ProteinTracker/Details/5

public ActionResult AddProtein(ProteinTrackingService model)
{
    proteinTrackingService.AddProtein(model.Total);
    model.Total = proteinTrackingService.Total;
    model.Goal = proteinTrackingService.Goal;

    return View("Index",model);
}
```

}

Comment: Do not use `ViewBag` to pass values to your view - initialize your model and set its properties and pass the model to the view. And in the view, bind to your model using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Total)` etc. Your manual html does not even have a name attribute so will not submit anything. Suggest you go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to understand the basics

Comment: You also have invalid html (nested forms) - remove the inner `<form>` tags.

Comment: How do i initialise and pass the model to the view. Do I need to do it in the index method

Comment: `var model = new ProteinTrackingService() { Total = x, Goal = y }; return View(model);`

Comment: Hi I have modified the code above and having issues diplaying the value in the view

Comment: What values? And what issues? And you cannot just change the original question and negate the comments and answers that have been given (I have rolled back the changes). If you want to show more code, then append it to the question - do not delete the original

Comment: Sorry stephen, I have added the questions above

Comment: So what problems are you still having? And have you added `@model yourAssembly.ProteinTrackingService` at the top of the view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106232/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-tom).

Comment: Yes I have added .The problem that i am facing is  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Total, "Total" )  <hr />  doesnt show me the total value. If I add                   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Total,new { @readonly = "readonly" }) to display the value  in front of it, it doesnt work. I think it is because I have already used @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Total)  in my view. If you see the last line below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `HttpPost` attribute to your action.Looking at your form `@using (Html.BeginForm( "AddProtein","ProteinTracker", FormMethod.Post))` , apparently you are sending a `post` request to your controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProtein(ProteinTrackingService model)
{
    proteinTrackingService.AddProtein(model.Total);
    model.Total = proteinTrackingService.Total;
    model.Goal = proteinTrackingService.Goal;

    return View("Index",model);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all your this syntax

```
using (Html.BeginForm("ProteinTracker", "AddProtein", FormMethod.Post))
```

already creates a **form** tag when html generates. No need to create from tag again in it.

So for your want, in view you need give to your input field a **name**

```
 <input id="Text1" type="text" value="TextInput" name="textname"/>
```

and add this name as parameter in your controller method like that

```
public ActionResult AddProtein(ProteinTrackingService model,string textname)
{
    // your code
    return View("Index");
}
```

It will pass your textfield value from view to controller. For clearing your concept you may visit [Loopcoder.com](http://loopcoder.com/pages/page/Data-passing-way-from-view-to-controller)

Comment: Hi I dont understand why you need to provide textname as a parameter to the AddProtein method. I thought that the model would contain that value. How do you initialise the model in the view

Comment: Ok after modified you almost done your task. To initialize model in your index page you have to set model reference in your view  as "@model yourprojectsolution.ProteinTrackingService" and then to show model data add @Html.Raw(Model.Total)  where you want to show your data